# Your manners need some 'editing'

Tags: word-usage

As far as I know, the meaning of 'edit' is - an act of making changes or corrections to a text or film. But, is it possible to use this word to make corrections in any other flaws e.g. in our daily life despite this meaning?

Answer (score 4):

Almost anything is possible in the right context.  However, "to edit" something is most often used in the context of making changes to some kind of media, like a document, a film, or a piece of music.  Books may be *edited* before they are published to make sure the wording is clean and correct, and accurately reflect the author's intended message.  Radio shows are edited to remove unwanted noise, or to reduce them to a particular length.  Film editing -- the process of selecting shots from the raw footage and combining them into sequences which create a finished motion picture -- is so important that it has its own Oscar award.

In these contexts it does mean "to *change* in order to *improve*" but, unless you want to convey the visual of snipping out parts of someone's manners and rearranging how they are organized, it really doesn't work.

In the context of "to correct", here are some options:  *amend, improve, fix, rectify, refine, set right, set straight*.

If you want to go with *metaphor*, then there are many options depending on what you want to say.  If, for example, you want to suggest that the person's manners are like dirty laundry which could use washing, then *clean up, launder, scrub, air out, cleanse, deodorize, soap, tidy,* and others.

Or you could suggest that their manners are crude but just need some finishing touches, like a raw gemstone, then *polish, clean up, finish, touch up, burnish, refine,* and various others.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a humourous comment if said in a suitable context. For example, if the speaker and the audience are authors, journalists, or editors.

It can also be understood in writing, if the context is clear. Placing the word *editing* in quotes suggests that it is metaphorical.

All that said, it is not the normal way to o express the idea. If you don't want to appear witty and possibly offend someone, stick to more general verbs such as "improve".